# Adding Click event on all elements with the same class without loop and jQuery

Tags: javascript, events, click

I have to write a code that run click event on all inputs with the same class without a loop and jquery.

What I come up with is :

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (click) {
    if (click.target.className == 'abc') {
        document.frame.screen.value += this.value;
    }
});
```

and click works but I got `undefined` instead of value that clicked input contain.

Comment: `this` is going to be `document.body` so `value` won't exist.

Answer (score 1):

> and click works but I got undefined instead of value that clicked input contain.

Because you've used `this` instead of `click.target` when getting the value; you wanted to use `click.target`:

```
document.frame.screen.value += click.target.value;
// Here -----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`this` in your handler will be `document.body`. You've correctly used `click.target` when checking the class, but not when getting the value.

Some notes:

- FWIW, the usual name for the event parameter in an event handler is `event` or `e`, not `click`.
- Elements can have multiple classes, which will all be in `className`. *If* that's a possible issue for you, you might look at `.classList.contains("abc")` instead. ([`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is available on all modern browsers, and you can polyfill it on obsolete ones.)
- It's not an issue for `input` elements, but in future if you want to do this with elements that can have descendant elements, you might need to have a loop to handle the possibility the click was on a descendant of your target element:

  ```
  var node = event.target;
  while (!node.classList.contains("abc")) {
      if (node === this) {
          return; // The click didn't pass through a matching element
      }
      node = node.parentNode;
  }
  // Use it here
  ```

Comment: Thank's a lot! I'm a toddler with javascript and don't fully understand DOM :)